# CSS - how to put divs in the correct position on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I want to put three divs on my webpage, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgeME.png), the pink div is the container for two other divs and I want to center the div on the webpage (vertically and horizontally). I prepared some [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfyacy25/), but obviously I suck at css, so the effect is far from the expected one... So far my css looks like this:

```
#intro2{
        background-color: #b0e0e6;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        }
#intro2 .image{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #aaaae6;
}
#intro2 .text{
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
}
```

Could you help me with that?
Thanks.

Comment: why you are not using float:left and right.

Comment: There are **many** layout methods and, arguably, using positioning is the worst..[**LearnLayout,com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:-

```css
#intro2{
 background-color: #b0e0e6;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 5px;
}
.clear{
 clear: both;
}
#intro2 .image{
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 background-color: #aaaae6;
}
#intro2 .text{
 float: right;
 width:50%;
 background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro" id="intro2">
 <div class="image" id="image1">
  <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" alt="simple" />
 </div>
 <div class="text" id="text1">
  <h1>Simple</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sodales sit amet mauris in blandit. Aenean sodales in dui eget facilisis. Vestibulum tempor risus dui, sed pharetra nulla auctor id. Sed purus odio, tempus et volutpat a, fermentum sit amet ante. Etiam eros mauris, rutrum at vehicula a, vehicula vitae nulla. Suspendisse non mattis turpis. Donec non convallis lacus. Nullam gravida diam et leo tempor vestibulum. Vivamus lorem nunc, bibendum eu lacinia quis, porta vel nisl. Sed vitae euismod augue. In at est lacinia ipsum feugiat feugiat. Praesent mollis posuere ante, eget maximus est mollis suscipit. Donec ullamcorper elit quis cursus gravida. Quisque leo risus, bibendum sed nisi ut, facilisis iaculis arcu. Pellentesque purus augue, fringilla tempus augue eget, ullamcorper condimentum leo.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show me the way of centering it also vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
#intro2{
        background-color: #b0e0e6;
        width: 50%;
        left:50%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:-25%;
 }
```

That way your container is centered on the page.

Comment: Works for your question - but you woudlnt build a website like that. But as I can see you are in the process of early learning - so keep going and you'll make your way :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would go with the absaloute positioning method you've gone for on this occasion. I think perhaps a `display:table` on the wrapper and `display:table-cell` on the children would give you more control over your style.

```
#intro2{
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#intro2 .image{
  background-color: #aaaae6;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#intro2 .text{
  background-color: #cccccc;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfyacy25/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfyacy25/3/

```
#intro2{
        background-color: #b0e0e6;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        }
#intro2 .image{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #aaaae6;
}
#intro2 .text{
   float: left;
    width: 50%;
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.intro{
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 5px;
}
.intro:before,.intro:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.intro:after {
    clear: both;
}
.image{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #aaaae6;
    float: left;
}
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.text{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    float: left;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfyacy25/5/)

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
 <div class="outter">
        <div class="innerleft">image goes here</div> 
        <div class="innerright">text goes here</div>
    </div>


.outter {width:100%; min-height:120px; background-color:red; padding:1% }
.innerleft {float:left; width:49%;background-color: green;min-height:120px; }
.innerright {float:right; width:49%;background-color: blue;min-height:120px; }
```